# htaccess redirection from messy url to clean one

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

An email blast was sent with some urls to my site, unfortunately somehow the links are showing some tracking from the tool i used and the site is choking on the URLs.

how can I redirect the incoming requests from

```
http://www.mysite.com/?utm_source=mysite+List&utm_campaign=xxxxxxxx-blah_blah_blah_blah&utm_medium=email#!/clients/myclient/
```

to

```
http://www.mysite.com/folder/page/
```

I tried using

```
Redirect http://www\\.mysite\\.com/\\?utm_source=mysite\\+List\\&utm_campaign=xxxxxxxx-blah_blah_blah_blah\\&utm_medium=email#!/clients/myclient/ http://www\\.mysite\\.com/folder/page/
```

but it didnt work.

the site already has some rules so it should redirect only when needed and let the other rules work

how can i achieve that?

thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot change the hashtag on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how precise you need to be, but the reason it isn't working is because it doens't understand query strings. You need to use a rewritecond and rewrite.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_source
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/folder/page/? [R=301,L]
```

this will redirect all traffic if it has utm_source in the query string.

Comment: thanks Ian, it kind of worked but it appends extra info after /page (because of the ?) how do i redirect to a fixed URL without any need to pass extra info?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the 301 part. I've edited it so it'll work. The ? on the end is what gets rid of the query string.

Comment: I had to change the second line to RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/? [R=301,L] for it to work. Not sure why, but all is good now. Thanks